# Jobs "cover letter" text box removes line breaks

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

After submitting a few applications in Jobs, I went to my Inbox to look around. To my dismay, I found that all of the line breaks have been smashed (not just in HTML display; they're actually gone, as far as I can tell with an AngularJS application)! This makes my cover letter, which I'd written out thoughtfully, into a Giant Wall O' Text.

Comment: You'll be pleased to know that the text was definitely not sent to the employer as a wall of text. It is, however, displayed in our messaging UI without link breaks. Will fix tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the report, the fix has just been pushed to prod.